# How to translate "what if" to Esperanto?

Tags: phrase-requests, questions

The English expression *what if* is an idiom meaning *what would happen if*, *what do I do if*, or something similar. An example is

> What if they don't like my cake?

Is there an expression in Esperanto for *what if*? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's as simple as you might think:

- Kio, se...
- Kaj kio, se...
- Kaj kio okazus, se...

from Acts 23:9

- *Ni trovas nenian malbonon en ĉi tiu viro; **kaj kio, se** parolis al li spirito aŭ anĝelo?*

Answer (score 4):

For "What would happen if", I would say "Kio, se...". But for "What do I do if..." or "what would you say if...", I would rather use the accusative, "Kion, se..." This is because you could say "Kion [fari], se..." or similar. In situations where it does not matter in English I believe you can just as well choose either in Esperanto.

The following excerpt from *La Respubliko* shows both options together (although I think the latter permits both choices).

> “Kaj **kio** okazas **se** oni dediĉas sin al sportoj kaj bone festenas sed ne tuŝas muzikon kaj filozofion? Mi kredas ke unue oni pleniĝas de fiero kaj vivo pro sia bonstata korpo kaj fariĝas pli kuraĝa pro tio.”
>
> “Certe.”
>
> “**Kion se** li faras nenion alian kaj amikiĝas kun neniu el la muzoj? Se ja ekzistas ia lernemo en li, sed ĝi ne gustumas edukiĝon nek scivolemon, nek partoprenas en diskutado nek en iu alia arto, ĉu ĝi ne febliĝas kaj fariĝas surda kaj blinda, ĉar ĝi neniam estas vekita aŭ subtenita kaj liaj sencoj ne estas rafinitaj?”
>
> “Tiel estas,” li respondis.